# Extract substring with regex?

Tags: crystal-lang

`String.match` returns a `MatchData`, but how can I get the matched string from [`MatchData`](http://crystal-lang.org/api/MatchData.html)?

```
puts "foo bar".match(/(foo)/)
```

output:

```
#<MatchData "foo" 1:"foo">
```

Sorry I am new to crystal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it via the well known group indexes, make sure to handle the nil (no match) case.

```rb
match = "foo bar".match(/foo (ba(r))/)
if match
  # The full match
  match[0] #=> "foo bar"
  # The first capture group
  match[1] #=> "bar"
  # The second capture group
  match[2] #=> "r"
end
```

You can find more information about `MatchData` in its [API docs](http://crystal-lang.org/api/index.html#http%3A//crystal-lang.org/api/MatchData.html)

Comment: http://carc.in/#/r/2ve I get the same error as there (using 0.7.3). Is it fixed in latest git?